# Position GMSMarker on bottom when clicked

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

When `GMSMarker` is clicked and `InfoWindow` is opened the camera moves to point where `GMSMarker` is at the center of the `GMSMapView`. How to change the camera move position that marker is at the bottom when moved?

When I implement GMS `didTapMarker` `delegate` method without `InfoWindow` everything is fine:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

    var point = mapView.projection.pointForCoordinate(marker.position)
    point.y = point.y - 200

    let camera = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(mapView.projection.coordinateForPoint(point))
    mapView.animateWithCameraUpdate(camera)

    return true
}
```

It positions marker on the bottom. But if I `return false` it shows InfoWindow and marker is centered again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapView.selectedMarker = marker` is missing in `didTapMarker` `delegate` method. The method should look like this:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

    var point = mapView.projection.pointForCoordinate(marker.position)
    point.y = point.y - 150

    let camera = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(mapView.projection.coordinateForPoint(point))
    mapView.animateWithCameraUpdate(camera)
    mapView.selectedMarker = marker
    return true
}
```